# list of items only adds one new item

Tags: vb.net

Following is the code I am attempting to use to import data from a database into a list of objects (from a class).   However, it only gets one item in the list when the loop finishes.  I used to place the data into a ListBox instead of a dynamic list of objects and that worked, so the data is being retrieved.

```
Public Class AnItem
    Public Item As String
    Public TheType As String
End Class

Public MyLists As List(Of AnItem) 

Private Sub AddToList()
    Dim i as integer
    Dim fs as AnItem

    For i = 0 To numberOfDataBaseitems
        Dim fs as new AnItem
        'fs.item = 'item 1'
        'fs.type = 'box'
        fs = getData(i)

        'ONLY one ITEM IS ADDED!!!!!!??????
        MyLists = New List(Of AnItem)  
        MyLists.Add(fs)
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: If an answer is valid for you, click on the tick to the left of the answer so that the question is marked as answered** and this makes sure that the person who posted it gets reputation. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this line within the loop:

```
MyLists = New List(Of AnItem)
```

is creating a new (empty) list every time around the loop.  1 item is added to the list.  Next time around the loop another new list object is created.

Just move this line to before this line:

```
For i = 0 To numberOfDataBaseitems
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line of code

```
Public MyLists As List(Of AnItem)
```

to

```
Public MyLists As New List(Of AnItem)
```

and remove this line of code

```
 MyLists = New List(Of AnItem)
```

Every time you execute the last line of code, the list is being declared as a new empty list. I'm guessing you added this because you were getting a NullReference exception. The reason you were getting the exception is because your declaration of MyLists at the beginning of my answer didnt include the `New` keyword